Mute speaker from systemd resume script
I'd like to mute my speaker (for a few seconds) after resuming from sleep, to avoid some annoying notification pings.
I have the following script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/muteonresume
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    pre)
            #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending
            touch /tmp/testpre;
    ;;
    post)
        #code execution AFTER resuming
        if [ amixer get Master | grep "\[on\]" ]
        then
            # already muted
            echo "already muted" > /tmp/testpost;
        else
            amixer set Master mute;
            echo "I muted now" > /tmp/testpost;
        fi
    ;;
esac

exit 0

The script is executed as expected, and puts "I muted now" in the log file /tmp/testpost. However, the speaker is not muted. Running amixer set Master mute standalone works as expected, both as myself and as root. But for some reason it does not work from this script. (Unless some other process unmutes after this happens, unbeknownst to me.)
Does anybody know why?
EDIT
Given the suggestions in the comments, I changed my setup and it now includes two scripts.
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/muteonresume:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    pre)
        touch /tmp/mutelog;
    ;;
    post)
        amixer get Master | grep -qF '[on]' ;
        ismuted=$?;
        if [ $ismuted -eq 1 ]  
        then
            echo `date` "already muted" >> /tmp/mutelog;
        else
           echo `date` "about to mute" >> /tmp/mutelog;
           nohup /usr/local/bin/sleepmute.sh & disown
           echo `date` "sent mute command"  >> /tmp/mutelog;
        fi
    
    ;;
esac

exit 0

and  /usr/local/bin/sleepmute.sh
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u myusername)
export DISPLAY=:0
echo `date` "enter sleepmute.sh" >> /tmp/mutelog;
#sleep 5;
amixer set Master mute;
echo `date` "muted from script sleepmute.sh" >> /tmp/mutelog;

With this configuration, I can see the LED indicator on my mute button light up after resuming but it shortly turns off again. The mutelog file contains, in order: "about to mute", "sent mute command", "enter sleepmute.sh", "muted from script sleepmute.sh". As expected.
So it seems to do what it should but someone else is unmuting. To counteract that, I uncomment the sleep 5 in sleepmute.sh to make my script wait a bit before it mutes. But then "muted from script sleepmute.sh" is never printed to the log, only "enter sleepmute.sh". So even though I run the script with nohup, it seems to get killed before it can sleep 5 seconds and do the muting.

You probably want to try sending the mute command to the background with a delay to let the resume process complete first before your command gets executed ... Please see: Network related part of a script will not run in /lib/systemd/system-sleep

... and your if ... then ... else conditional statement might not be working as you intended.

The problem with audio is that there are various possible packages that sit on top of alsa that can manipulate mute and volume through libraries and servers without running amixer. Until recently, pulseaudio had this role,but now pipewire is taking over. You would need to see if either of these are installed and in use. The command pactl is used by pulseaudio, I don't know about pipewire.

You have a syntax error in the line
if [ amixer get Master | grep "\[on\]" ]

because the test command, [...], does not execute commands within it. You
can just remove it:
if amixer get Master | grep "\[on\]"

or if you don't need to see the matching output lines printed, add -q:
if amixer get Master | grep -q "\[on\]"

Also, when possible, use single quotes rather than double quotes with
strings that don't need interpolation. And you can also use grep's -F
option to make your string not a pattern:
if amixer get Master | grep -q -F '[on]'


Thanks. I modified the script to do following if instead: amixer get Master | grep -qF '[on]' ;   ismuted=$?;   if [ $ismuted -eq 1 ];
I have verified that this if clause works. But there seems to be another problem where someone else unmutes

You could rename amixer to myamixer then create a shell script amixerto do  ps fax >>/tmp/testps; exec myamixer "$@" to try to log what it calling amixer. There may be other commands that can unmute or set the volume.

meuh that sounds like a smart idea. I tried it and it does the right thing when running amixer manually. (Although the only trace in the testps log is ps fax, not amixer itself.) But the file is not touched when running amixer`  through my resume script, even though I can see the mute LED indicator turning on and off.
